# Mocha with Grunt: Cannot find module that exists

Tags: json, gruntjs, mocha.js

I am having issues with Mocha finding a module that exists. I have a data folder that contains all my test data. This folder exists and is at the correct directory (confirmed with pwd). When I run the test using mocha test *filename* the tests pass, but when I use `grunt test` I get the following error.

```
Running "mochaTest:tests" (mochaTest) task
>> Mocha exploded!
>> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/Documents/project/project_dispatcher/tests/data'
>>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>>     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
>>     at /Users/user/Documents/project/project_dispatcher/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
>>     at Array.forEach (native)
>>     at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/user/Documents/project/project_dispatcher/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:14)
>>     at MochaWrapper.run (/Users/user/Documents/project/project_dispatcher/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/lib/MochaWrapper.js:51:15)
>>     at /Users/user/Documents/project/project_dispatcher/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/mocha-test.js:86:20
>>     at capture (/Users/user/Documents/project/project_dispatcher/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/mocha-test.js:33:5)
Warning: Task "mochaTest:tests" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I am assuming this is a config issue, but I am lost as to what is causing it. I have the following structure:

->test

-->testfile.js

-->data

---->datafile.json

And I include the json file using:

```
var requestObj = require('./data/workflowRequest.json');
```

Is the ./ no longer valid because I am using Grunt which is located above the test folder? I am also confused because the stack trace only contains mocha files, and no test files that I wrote.

**Edit** Grunt code may be useful too

```
mochaTest: {
    tests: {
        src:['tests/**/*'],
        options: {
            reporter: 'spec'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        src:['tests/**/*'],
        options: {
            reporter: 'nyan'
        }
    },
    tap: {
        src:['tests/**/*'],
        options: {
            reporter: 'tap'
        }
    }
},
```